# how to select a folder while browsing in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to select a folder while browsing,
I have implemented like

```
<input name="name" type="file"/>
```

with this I am able to select a file,but I want to select a folder
can any one help me.....

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. What do you expect to achieve by selecting a folder? Are you trying to upload the entire contents of a directory to the server? Why have you tagged this JavaScript? Are you guessing that the solution will involve JS? Are you wanting to do something with the directory using JS?

Comment: may be flash has a solution

Comment: @Quentin: He might want to indicate a folder to communicate with an application on the client. Why does everyone suspect a hacker kid when a question on input type file and javascript is asked lol.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood it, you are limited to selecting individual files and not folders in the browser.

Comment: Under JavaScript? Under JavaScript you are limited to no files and no folders. You can use browser to do that, but that has nothing to do with JavaScript.

Comment: Actually it depends entirely on where he's using the JavaScript if you want to be that pedantic. In theory as long as the host provides an interface to do it. But we can make an educated assumption that given he's flagged this is javascript and html he's trying to do this in a browser. I could be wrong of course...

Comment: Yeah. I'm not really pedantic, I just wanted to emphasize the difference between JavaScript and browser. Still a correct answer of course.

Comment: Yeh that's fair enough. The question is bad anyhow, asked for JavaScript but supplied HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Since "HTML5" it is possible to enable multiple file selection by adding the input element "multiple"-attribute as long as the rowser you are using supports this:

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

However, you cannot enable the selection of a complete folder using JavaScript